Redirecting output to file removes newline
I wrote two different C codes.
hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World\n");
}

hello2.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello World");
}

I compiled a ran the two codes and redirected the output to two files "hello.txt" and "hello2.txt" respectively using the > operator. Specifically, the commands were as follows.
$ gcc -o hello hello.c
$ gcc -o hello2 hello2.c 
$ ./hello > hello.txt 
$ ./hello2 > hello2.txt

Curiously, both files look the same in vim, even though while printing in stdout the first program outputs a newline in the end while the second one does not. I thought the first one will end with a newline in vim but it does not.
Why does this happen? And How can I fix it so that the ending \n is not ignored while redirecting to a file? Thanks.
Update: In notepad++ the files are looking different: "hello.txt" file ends with a newline indeed whereas "hello2.txt" don't have a newlline. But in vim they are the same

What were the actual commands you ran?

I ran the following commands:

gcc -o hello hello.c
gcc -o hello2 hello2.c
./hello > hello.txt
./hello2 > hello2.txt

In VIM Both files contain 'Hello World' without any newline in the end

"both files look the same" -- How do you view them? "Look" != "are", so this says nothing about the actual content.

I think muru meant the commands you ran to estabilish the files are the same. The first one most definetly should include a newline and the second one shouldn't

[edit] your post to show the exact commands you ran, and the exact output you got. Just copy-paste from the terminal into a code block. We don't know what you see, so if you don't show it, we can't interpret it for you.

The reason is you're inspecting the files using Windows (or Notepad++ in Wine or something), and on Windows \n is not sufficient to end the line, you need \r\n.

try cat hello.txt vs. cat hello2.txt. Or better yet, od -c (or e.g. od -tx1z on GNU).

also, have a look at the editing help, the very first point about code blocks. (and note the edit made to your post earlier, revision 3)

Don't view the output file with vim, view it with od -a or a similar tool.

Thanks. The last answer is of some help.
od -a hello.txt gives
0000000   H   e   l   l   o  sp   W   o   r   l   d  nl
0000014
od -a hello2.txt gives
0000000   H   e   l   l   o  sp   W   o   r   l   d
0000013
So, vim is indeed the issue
